# Dropdown selection not getting cleared

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to clear the selected value from the dropdown but still the value is persisting. It is the same behavior using `@Html.DropDownListFor`

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [Route("/Home/Index")]
    [Route("/Home/Index/{Category}")]
    [Route("/Home/Index/{Category}/{Type}")]
    public IActionResult Index(HomeModel model)
    {
        // Issue is here
        // for url: home/index/accessories/test
        // "Category" is cleared if it is not valid "type"
        // but still "Accessories" remains selected in the drop down
        if (model.Type != "Electronics" && model.Type != "Furniture")
        {
            model.Category = string.Empty;
        }

        return View(new HomeModel() { Category = model.Category, Type = model.Type });
    }
```

**View**

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeModel

<select asp-for="Category" asp-items="@Model.Categories"></select>
<select asp-for="Type" asp-items="@Model.Types"></select>
```

**Model**

```
public class HomeModel
{
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Computers & Laptops", Value="Computers-Laptops" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Accessories", Value="Accessories" },
    };

    public List<SelectListItem> Types { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Electronics", Value="Electronics" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text="Furniture", Value="Furniture" },
    };
}
```

### UPDATE

I tried to add a empty value to the Category dropdown and still no luck.

```
 <select asp-for="Category" asp-items="@Model.Categories">
        <option value="">Select Category</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: You don't have an empty value in your select list.  Try adding a Text="" option.

Comment: @KevinRaffay It is still not working after adding a empty value

Comment: I guess, it is picking the value from the Route

Comment: What html is generated in browser?

Comment: Are you posting or anything to the method when the error occurs? Or just visiting a "fresh" link?

Comment: @JLe, I am just opening the link in the browser with that url. It works for all other values except for the blank category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is within the `ModelState`. What happens is that when the URL parameters are bound to the view model, the values are added to the model state dictionary. When the view is rendered, not only your `HomeModel` is passed to the view, but underneath the scenes the `ModelState` is passed as well - and it has a higher [priority](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/321327f84b2b22dcff2e9beb06a9a64236c5cced/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs#L1002) than the view model. So while you reset the `model.Category`, the `Category` key in the `ModelState` still has the value `accessories` and that is why it is being selected in the dropdown.

The solution is simple, call `.Clear()` to wipe out the model state and make your view model win:

```
[Route("/Home/Index")]
[Route("/Home/Index/{Category}")]
[Route("/Home/Index/{Category}/{Type}")]
public IActionResult Index(HomeModel model) {
    // Issue is here
    // for url: home/index/accessories/test
    // "Category" is cleared if it is not valid "type"
    // but still "Accessories" remains selected in the drop down
    if (model.Type != "Electronics" && model.Type != "Furniture") {
        model.Category = string.Empty;
    }
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(new HomeModel() { Category = model.Category, Type = model.Type });
}
```